# PowerShell find number of files in users homedirectory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, expression, home-directory

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that pulls the number of files of each users home directory in Active Directory.  I've come up with the following script but it's not actually getting the number of files, my file count is 0 for each user.  What did I miss in the Expression?  I tried % in place of ? and I tried adding ! in front of $_ with incorrect results.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties * -SearchBase "OU=Information Technology,`
OU=User Accounts,DC=net,DC=local" | ft name, homedirectory, homedrive,`
@{Name='Files'; Expression={(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Ignore`
| ?{$_.HomeDirectory}).count}} -A
```

Comment: Active Directory only contains the path to the home directory, the files are on the file system. you would need to use Get-Child Items on the $_.HomeDirectory folder, and count those.

Comment: The OP is attempting to do that. Try it with Select-Object instead of Format-Table. The thumbrule is to filter left and format right. Once you get the right info from Select-Object you can Format-Table all you want.

Comment: Good catch @randoms that works except for those that don't have a homedirectory in their profile it gives me the files and folders of where I happen to be when I run the script.  Otherwise it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [randoms points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407579/powershell-find-number-of-files-in-users-homedirectory/49409153?noredirect=1#comment85816516_49407579), you'll need to supply `$_.HomeDirectory` as an argument to `Get-ChildItem`.

To avoid running `Get-ChildItem` when a `HomeDirectory` attribute is empty or doesn't exist, you could put an `if` statement in the expression (split into multiple statements for readability here):

```
$ITUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties homedirectory,homedrive -SearchBase "OU=Information Technology,OU=User Accounts,DC=net,DC=local" 
$ITUsers |Format-Table name, homedirectory, homedrive,@{Name='Files'; Expression={
  if(Test-Path $_.homedirectory){
    @(Get-ChildItem $_.homedirectory -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction Ignore).Count
  } 
  else {
    0
  }
} -AutoSize
```

Comment: I did thanks and it worked.  Your IF statement helped eliminate the users that didn't have a home directory.  Thank You!